# (Swift) Assign UIDatePicker selected date to UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore, uitextfield, uidatepicker

First let me state all the other code you see works as desired except for the UIDatePicker. Right now when I click on the dateTextField the `UIDatePicker` shows up and I can select a date but when I click the Done button the Date selected is not in the `UITextField` assigned to it.

One area that may be a place to focus is the doneClicked function. When I initially created it I did not have the (@objc) in front of it and it gave me an error.

/*Argument of '#selector' refers to instance method `doneClicked()` that is not exposed to Objective-C*/

So I added (@objc) and the error went away but as stated above the date selected from the `UIDatePicker` is not being saved in the `UITextField`.

If you would please explain and show where my code is wrong and how to fix it.

Any help is greatly appreciated in this matter thank you very much.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseUI

class TrainViewController: UIViewController{

@IBOutlet weak var trainField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var locationField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var engineField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var dateTextField: UITextField!

let datePicker = UIDatePicker()

@IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.saveText()

    trainField.text?.removeAll()
    locationField.text?.removeAll()
    engineField.text?.removeAll()
    dateTextField.text?.removeAll()

     self.view.endEditing(true)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    createDatePicker()
}

   func saveText() {
    let trainText = self.trainField.text!
    let locationText = self.locationField.text!
    let engineText = self.engineField.text!
    let dateStart = self.dateTextField.text!

let db = Firestore.firestore()
let dict = ["train_text": trainText,
            "location_text": locationText,
            "engine_text": engineText,
            "dateStart_text": dateStart]
db.collection("users").addDocument(data: dict)
   }

func createDatePicker(){

    //format the display of our datepicker
    datePicker.datePickerMode = .date

    //assign date picker to our textfield
    dateTextField.inputView = datePicker

    //create a toolbar
    let toolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.sizeToFit()

    //add a done button on this toolbar
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: nil, action: #selector(doneClicked))
    toolbar.setItems([doneButton], animated: true)

    dateTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
}

@objc func doneClicked(){
    //format the date display in textfield
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none
  }

}

extension TrainViewController : UITextFieldDelegate {

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not assigning the date in textFiled.

Like : `dateTextField.text = dateString`

in doneClicked click, get the date form datePicker and assign to dateTextField.

Code:

```
@objc func doneClicked(){
    //format the date display in textfield
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none
    let dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(datePicker.date)
    print(dateString)
    dateTextField.text = dateString
  }
```

Comment: This is perfect thank you so much! Now that it is pointed out of course I should have added the code to the doneClicked function. Really appreciate this man.